# How do I get my AutoHotKey script to activate upon click an area of the screen, then deactivate until a different area of the screen is clicked?

Tags: autohotkey

I am writing my first script in AutoHotKey.  What I am trying to achieve is as follows:

When a certain area of the screen is clicked I want the script to run where it will click the specific co-ords on the screen.  I then want the script to be *disabled* until I click a different area of the screen (as specified within the `else if`).

The current script is sporadically activating AFTER it has already run once (after `c` has been set to `1`)

```
c = 0

#IfWinActive, ahk_exe C:\Program Files (x86)\Hearthstone\Hearthstone.exe 
~LButton::
MouseGetPos, x, y
if (c = 0 and x > 1700 and x < 2150  and y > 1600 and y < 1800) {
  c = 1
  Tooltip, c is %c%
  Sleep, 1000
  MouseGetPos, currentX, currentY
  CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
  Click, Right, 1940, 410
  Sleep, 200
  Click, 1610, 200
  MouseMove, currentX, currentY
  return
}

else if (x > 2620 and x < 3000  and y > 1590 and y < 1950) {
  c = 0
  Tooltip, c is %c%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually works.  This numpty was running an older version of the script concurrently and that was what was causing the issues.

So anyone who needs to do something similar - here's the script for you!  =)